# Umbraco Controller Without Source Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

Our company hired a contractor to build a web-site, which works fantastic.  However, the source code was never provided and they've gone out of business.  So at this point we have a published solution, that is our web-site.

I can see all the Razor utilized from the Umbraco backend and when I use the "Open Web-Site" functionality of Visual Studio 2017.  The issue I notice, that in the `bin` they've added a reference to a library for our specific functionality.  This file has a lot of compiler generated code through Dot Peek.

I can see this in Dot Peek:

```
public class NewsroomController : SurfaceController
{
     // Logic
}
```

Is there a way in Umbraco to see expose this .dll contents?  To get the actual code?  I'm assuming a bulk of the logic that is failing, is due to it being `dynamic`.  Let me rephrase, appearing as "compiler generated" is dynamic.

Comment: You won't be able to see the contents of a compiled library through Umbraco. The best you're going to get is a de-compiled site and library through Dot Peek.

Comment: @allen.mn That is what I was afraid of.

Comment: I find IL Spy can sometimes give better results than DotPeek - http://ilspy.net/ - give that a go perhaps...